# EC2 virtual server receives requests but cannot access another host

Tags: server, apache2, connection, amazon-ec2, virtualhost

I have a virtual machine in Amazon AWS Ubuntu where I installed Apache2, PHP5 and MySql. 
Everything was running well, my website was running fine on it.

Suddenly the virtual machine stopped accessing other hosts. This happens for every request.

I found this out when a PHP script began giving error

'connection timed out' when using the file_get_contents() function

```
<?php echo file_get_contents('http://example.com'); ?>
```

I went to the command line of the server via SSH, and tried to ping an external host `ping google.com` and nothing. 
I tried to use apt-get to update the system `sudo apt-get update` and also does not connect.

The funny thing is that if I try to access the site, the server usually receives the request and return the site to the browser. ie, the internet connection is there.

Another detail is that the access to `file_get_contents() PHP` I'm trying to do is also on the same site, not on an external site, and yet that timed out.

Here the result of netstat -lnp command:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      957/sshd        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1098/mysqld     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      957/sshd        
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      1145/apache2    
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1145/apache2    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           560/dhclient    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:18032           0.0.0.0:*                           560/dhclient    
udp6       0      0 :::60689                :::*                                560/dhclient    
Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   PID/Program name    Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8236     785/dbus-daemon     /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     6500     1/init              @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8549     965/acpid           /var/run/acpid.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     6797     324/systemd-udevd   /run/udev/control
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8919     1098/mysqld         /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Here the result of eating iptables-L:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

What might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

For those who had the same problem like me, went to the bottom to find the nameserver was set to the ip of amazon.

So I edited `/etc/resolv.conf` and put the google nameservers

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

and it worked. Hope this helps someone.